# Schema of a database storing running workouts

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I am currently modeling and populating a database with my running workouts, using MySQL.
At this moment, I have 4 tables : runners, sessions (with general infos), specifics (in case the session aims for a specific training (running intervals). And the 4th, which I have been force to add is actually intervals.
Though, I'd like this 4th table to be in the 3rd.
Let me explain. The specific part of a session is composed by intervals. These intervals can be linear (example: 10 times one minute or 12 times 300 meters), or progressive or/and regressive (example: 1x15s/15s, 2x30s/30s 1x15s/15s (before slash being intense part, after being recovery)).

I ended up with that schema:
[Running Database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvrOR.png). With this schema, in case my intervals are linear (which they are most of the time), I'm forced to create a single interval for each of the 10 I have done (for example), but they have the same values. I find that really repetitive. So that's why I am here, looking for ideas. I have thought of putting a formatted string in specifics, which would contains the form of the specific part of my workout. What do you think about that ?

Here's the script of the database creation, if you have any comment to make, I'd be glad to hear them:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS runners, sessions, specifics, intervals;

CREATE TABLE `runners` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(100),
  `first_name` VARCHAR(100),
  `date_birth` DATE,
  `date_death` DATE,
  `sex` VARCHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session_date` DATE,
  `session_type` VARCHAR(20),
  `validity` BOOLEAN,
  `duration` TIME,
  `distance` DECIMAL(5, 2),
  `speed` DECIMAL(4, 2),
  `heart_rate` TINYINT UNSIGNED,
  `sensations` TINYINT UNSIGNED,
  `runner_id` INT
);

CREATE TABLE `specifics` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nb_series` TINYINT UNSIGNED,
  `recovery` TIME,
  `speed` DECIMAL(4, 2),
  `heart_rate` TINYINT UNSIGNED,
  `session_id` INT
);

CREATE TABLE `intervals` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `distance` DECIMAL(5, 2),
  `duration` TIME,
  `recovery` TIME,
  `specific_id` INT
);

ALTER TABLE `sessions` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`runner_id`) REFERENCES `runners` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `specifics` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`session_id`) REFERENCES `sessions` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `intervals` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`specific_id`) REFERENCES `specifics` (`id`);
```

EDIT:

I have been modifying my database lately, and I came up with this database model.
Rather than having a varchar containing the specific part of my running session (which is difficult to manipulate, as several variables are contained in one field, and it's not a normalized model), I chose to create two new tables:

- an interval table containing a linear sequence of intervals (example: 3 x 100 m/20" or 4 x 1'/1' - respectively: 3 repetitions of 100 m, with 20 s recovery, and 4 repetitions of one minute, with one minute recovery);
- and an intervals_sequences table containing interval sequences, if the specific part of the session is not linear (example: 3 x 200 m/40", 2 x 400 m/1', 1 x 600 m/1'30".
  Here's the diagram: [Running database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5SUY.png).

However, I've noticed a despicable redundancy in the intervals_sequences table, and I can't see how to remove it.
Each column, sequence, actually contains the id of a sequence of linear intervals.
Do you have any ideas to make this model more maintainable and manipulable?

I thank you in advance for your help, and wish you a beautiful day!